# PHP object can not access variable

Tags: php

Using the following:

```
$last_book = tz_books::getLast($request->db, "WHERE book_id='{$request->book_id}'");
```

I get the following php object array,

```
[0] => tz_books Object
    (
        [db:tz_books:private] => com Object

        [id] => 64BEC207-CA35-4BD2
        [author_id] => 4F4755B4-0CE8-4251
        [book_id] => 8FC22AA0-4A60-4BFC
        [date_due] => variant Object

    )
```

I then want to use the author_id, but for some reason it's not working.

Trying to use:

```
$tz_books->author_id;
```

Using print_r($last_book); prints the array to the console just fine. And Doing the following just to see if the correct variable was being used:

```
$author = $tz_books->author_id;
print_r($author);
```

Nothing is printed to the console, and even after digging through the php manual and trying a lot of alternatives, I can't seem to grab that variable. I'm hoping i'm making a rookie mistake and overlooking something stupid. Thank you for any help!

Edit: Class definition

```
private $db;
public $id;
public $author_id;
public $book_id;
public $date_due;

public function __construct($db, $values=null) {
    $this->db = $db;
    if ( $values != null ) {
        foreach ( $values as $var => $value ) {
            $this->$var = $value;
        }
    }
}

public static function retrieveAll($db, $where='', $order_by='') {
    $result_list = array();
    $query = 'SELECT '.
            'id, '.
            'author_id, '.
            'book_id, '.
            'date_due '.
        "FROM tz_books $where $order_by";

    $rs = $db->Execute($query);

    while ( !$rs->EOF ) {
        $result_list[] = new tz_books($db, array(
            'id' => clean_id($rs->Fields['id']->Value),
            'author_id' => clean_id($rs->Fields['author_id']->Value),
            'book_id' => clean_id($rs->Fields['book_id']->Value),
            'date_due' => $rs->Fields['date_due']->Value,
        ));
        $rs->MoveNext();
    }
    $rs->Close();
    return $result_list;
}
```

Comment: Am I seeing this right? If so, try `$last_book[0]->author_id;` or `$tz_books = $last_book[0];`

Comment: The question is confusing. Is the variable `$last_book` or `$tz_books`? Because `$last_book` is an *array*, not an object, if I understand your example.

Comment: Do you have the class definition? It is possible that the author_id is a private property. Also, there may be a getter method. And if not, you can make one. Post your class definition and I'll help you.

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer your question, but why not return an array (using `mysql_fetch_assoc`, for example) instead of an object ? Now to address the problem, can you post the full code of the `tz_books::getLast()` function (or at least function declaration and the building/returning of the result)?

Comment: Updated with the class definition. New to this, looks like the $tz_books[0]->author_id; works...Thank you!. If there's a better way to get and use data, please let me know! :)..thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result object seems to be an array of books with 1 element.
Try

```
echo $tz_books[0]->author_id;
```

BTW, it also looks like you're escaping input by putting single quotes. This is not a reliable/recommended method. Use a database-specific escape function like [this](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: thank you!... Works, and great info for me. Had been going off another example file I had, had no idea using single quotes in that way was not reliable. Much appreciated :)!

Comment: no problem O-)
it's bit more than simple "reliability"; have a read [here](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)